# Facebook's l.php

Tags: php, facebook

So recently i gave my friend a URL on facebook chat while we were discussing on how much further we have to go on a booking system, my friend says he cant open the link, when i tried clicking it worked but what caught my eye was the referring URL by facebook:

> https://www.facebook.com/**l.php**?u=https%3A%2F%2F192.168.42.149%2FIS314%2Freservations.php

I was intrigued by the l.php (L.PHP), what actually does l.php do? I googled and a author speculated something on privacy at this page http://www.codehesive.com/index.php/archive/facebook-privacy-and-the-mystery-of-l-php/ but nothing too certain. So i was wondering if anyone has a clear idea of what l.php could be, i find this interesting (weird i know). Thanks!

Comment: This question can really only be answered by someone at Facebook that has knowledge of the actual code behind these redirects.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I don't think it's a good fit for the [so] format as most answers here will be speculation without the ability to give a concrete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one can know what exactly that script does but the developers at Facebook.

I presume they track all outgoing links from Facebook to get some statistics on them and on the users. After that it just sends you to the external page.

Comment: What a dystopian prediction!

Comment: This might also be used for content moderation?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following article [Facebook, privacy and the mystery of l.php](http://web.archive.org/web/20160826060705/http://www.codehesive.com:80/index.php/archive/facebook-privacy-and-the-mystery-of-l-php/) which says:

> Unless it’s from a public page, all you’re bound to see is one simple
>   referring URL: http://www.facebook.com/l.php. Facebook ‘wraps’ all
>   links on Facebook within this simple file — once you click on a link
>   in Facebook, l.php will ‘redirect’ you to the actual URL. Why Facebook
>   does this is unclear.

So now you have more questions to answer.

<sup>Update: Sorry, I just realised that you posted actually the same link.</sup>